# How to use jQuery .slideUp() to make a floating button appear in the corner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I'm trying to get a button to slide up and appear in the bottom right corner of the screen after a user is on the page for 30 seconds.

How to do I start with the div hidden and then make it slide in from the bottom as it appears?

This hasn't worked so far:

```
<div id="buttonContainer" class="">
  <button>Submit</button>  
</div>
```

```js
 function showSurvey(){
     $('#buttonContainer').slideUp('slow');
    };
```

```css
#surveySpot {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 20px;
 right: 20px
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `showSurvey()` ?

Comment: If you're not against adding another library, try out animate.css. It'll do what you want without jQuery. https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: slideUp doesn't make the element move, but hides it with a slide animation from the bottom

Answer (score 2):

JQuery's `.slideup()` doesn't actually move the element, it's just an animation trick to hide and show elements.

Instead, you can do this entirely with [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations), no need for jQuery at all. You can create a keyframe animation to move the element into frame and then set a 30 second animation delay.

```css
.survey {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  background: cornflowerblue;

  /* translate off the bottom of the screen */
  transform: translateY(100%);
  /* call the slideup keyframes and have them take 500 milliseconds */
  animation: slideup 500ms ease-out forwards;
  /* delay the start of the animation by 5 second, you can use 30 */
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

/* a very simple from/to keyframe we can call with the "animation" property */
@keyframes slideup {
  from { transform: translateY(100%); }
  to   { transform: translateY(0); }
}
```

```html
<p>Wait 5 seconds for the survey to show...</p>

<div class="survey">This is a survey</div>
```